Unsupported class file major version 61 when upgrade from java 11 to 17, wildfly from 23 to 24
I have just upgrade my java version to java 17 and wildfly 24.
In jboss runtime, runtime JRE, I choose
Exectution Environment: JavaSE-17
the pom is
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                    <!--<source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
.........

then I right click the pom.xml and choose maven > update project, then I add the ear to wildfly 24.0.1,
but when I start the wildfly, many error like

22:34:45,240 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader]
(ServerService Thread Pool -- 94) Context initialization failed:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
to read candidate component class: VFS resource
["/C:/wildfly-24.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/hk/housingauthority/slis/annotation/InjectUserIdentity.class"];
nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM
ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java
class file version that isn't supported yet: VFS resource
["/C:/wildfly-24.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/hk/housingauthority/slis/annotation/InjectUserIdentity.class"];
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported
class file major version 61   at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:454)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:90)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1391)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1371)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:179)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:514)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:394)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:337)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:305)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:637)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at
deployment.SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war//hk.housingauthority.slis.web.SLISContextListener.contextInitialized(SLISContextListener.java:55)
at
io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
at
io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
at
io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
at
io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
at
io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
at
io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at
org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at
org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at
org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at
org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

I see the statement

Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader
failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file
version that isn't supported yet: VFS resource
["/C:/wildfly-24.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/SLISEAR-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear/SLIS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/hk/housingauthority/slis/annotation/InjectUserIdentity.class"];
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported
class file major version 61

but how to fix it?
is the .class already in java 17 version?
is it due to spring-core 5.2.2 not compatible with java 17?

What Java version do you run Maven with?

Sorry but how to know? in pom.xml, I set maven-compiler-plugin, release to 17, is this enough? then in eclipse, I just right click the pom.xml and choose Maven > Update Project.
In eclipse Window > preferences, java Configurator, I choose "Use execution environment based on maven-compiler-plugin configuration.

Ok, spring problem, spring-core 5.2.2 is not compatible with java 17, after upgrade spring-core from  5.2.2 to 5.3.20, problem solved.
